# Signed INF driver appears unsigned when added to installer.exe

Tags: driver, nsis, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

Our company recently purchased an EV-Code Signing Certificate from Digicert. We used it to sign a simple INF file that uses Microsoft's usbser.sys following the process described in Kernel-Mode Code Signing Walkthrough. When we install the driver through Hdwwiz.exe the driver 
appears signed and Windows Security message asking "Would you like to install this device software?" appears. We are able to see all information needed such as Name & Publisher name. Nevertheless, when the driver is installed we receive error: "This device cannot start. (Code 10)". Same thing happens in Windows 7 x 86, Windows 7 x 64, Windows 8 x 86, Windows 8 x 64, Windows 8.1 x 86  and Windows 8.1 x 64. 
Now issue come when we add inf and cat file to our installer.exe. Then when installing Windows Security message appears: "Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software". Any ideas what can cause the problem?

Comment: Are you saying the driver fails to load even when NSIS is not involved?

Comment: Yes because the device is not connected to the machine, so I imagine that this is the reason why we receive "This device cannot start. (Code 10)".